# ubuntu 13.10 won't install it just reboot the pc when terying to install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

im having a problem in installing any version of Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 or inside it, it seems that the only solution is to format my pc but I don't like to do that. When booting from the usb stuck the option install alongside Windows 7 doesn't appear in the list. So I just choose to install Ubuntu inside but it just shutdown and restarted to Windows. Is it there any solution?

Comment: no it is a windows seven  and it was working properly i installed ubuntu several times i was having heat problem but it was working but know it just won't and no i installed  windows by my self

Answer (score 0):

Could be your hard drive. Try checking your Drive for Errors with "chkdsk" or any 3rd party tool.
It can also be an overheating issue.
You know there is something wrong when the installer doesn't see your existant Windows OS.

Comment: the over heating problem exist before but it does'nt stop the installation and i did check my drive with chkdsk but still the problem persist .

Comment: im also trying o find a sollution to the hating problem i just found out it is because of the hybrid graphical card.

Comment: here is my suggestion,install cpu-freq on the live session and  force Ubuntu to to run at the lowest speed.